# From DNA to final traits of microorganisms?

Tags: genetics, dna, gene-expression

From the answer of this [topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41078/what-is-the-instructional-language-of-dna), could someone indicate me a book or article about how DNA set the phenotype of microorganisms? For example, showing how DNA changes the shape of such a cell or how DNA sets the concentration of a such mineral inside the cytoplasm.